# Javascript global variable not modified in a callback

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to loop through every 1000 elements in a S3 bucket. This is because 1000 elements in the maximum returned by a get request. If there are more than 1000 elements, it get paginated, and the get request returns with a field call IsTruncated as true, and a marker (NextMarker) element to pass to the next call, letting the next get request start at the next 1000 elements.

I'm getting the data from the get request as a parameter in a callback function, and attempting to store the two pieces of above information in global variables for use in an outer loop. However, the outer loop goes off to infinity because the global variables are never modified in my get request callback function. I've tried using window.variable inside the callback to no avail. Could anyone help me restructure this code to accomplish my goals?

Thanks

Outter loop is commented out for debugging purposes. There are a number of debugging console.log statement I used to determined the root of the problem.

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
                    s3_bucket = "link_to_s3_bucket";
                    var go = true;
                    var marker = "";
                    //while(go){
                            console.log('pass');
                            console.log(s3_bucket + marker);
                            $.get(
                                    s3_bucket+marker,
                                    "{}",
                                    function(data) {
                                            $(data).find('Key').each(function(i, key) {
                                                    key = key.innerHTML;
                                                    $("<a />", {
                                                            href : s3_bucket+key,
                                                            text : key
                                                    }).prependTo("#links");
                                            $("<br />").prependTo("#links");
                                            });
                                            window.go = $(data).find('IsTruncated')[0].innerHTML;
                                            window.marker = "&marker=" + $(data).find('NextMarker')[0].innerHTML;
                                    },
                                    "xml"
                            );
                    //}
                    console.log(go);
                    console.log(marker);

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data returns asynchronously from Amazon, so those variables haven't been defined yet when you call those console logs. Put the console logs inside of the callback after the variable assignments.

Comment: Yes, I've done that and it does in fact print the correct values, however it doesn't help me much as I need the variable assingments to change in the global context for my loop to work.

Comment: they are global because they are on the window object which is the browser's global object, so they are changing.

Comment: @user3594685 - They are changing.  The new values just aren't there UNTIL the `$.get()` function finishes asynchronously (which means sometime later).  If you want to use a return result from an Ajax call, you MUST use it from the completion handler of the Ajax call, either by putting your code that uses it there or by calling a function from there and passing the data to it.  You can't just use it from a global variable like you are doing.  If you are going to use asynchronous calls like `$.get()` you HAVE to program asynchronously.

Comment: He can use it from the global variable. But it will be undefined until the request returns.